# C# ReceiveBufferSize shows incorrect value

Tags: c#, image, tcpclient, networkstream

`client.ReceiveBufferSize` doesn't give the right received byte size.

So I have tried to use `client.Client.SendFile("FileName.png")` instead and still gives the same result. I have also done a check to make sure that the image that it was sending was more than 64KB and it did show it was sending more than 64KB (From the client side).

Server Code:

```
TcpListener server = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any,12345);
TcpClient client = server.AcceptTcpClient();
NetworkStream clientstream = client.GetStream();
                byte[] ImageByte = new byte[client.ReceiveBufferSize];
                int ReceiveCount = await clientstream.ReadAsync(ImageByte,0,ImageByte.Length);
                File.WriteAllBytes("Screenshot.png",ImageByte);
```

Client Code:

```
TcpClient client = new TcpClient();
client.Connect(IPAddress.Parse("123.456.789.123"), 12345);
                    byte[] imagebyte = File.ReadAllBytes("ImageCaptured.temp");
                    client.GetStream().Write(imagebyte, 0, imagebyte.Length);
                    File.Delete("ImageCaptured.temp");
```

The `client.ReceiveBufferSize` suppose to show around ~128KB but only shows up to 64KB exactly.

Comment: Please provide [MCVE]. There is a good chance that `client.ReceiveBufferSize` is 64k... also review your post and see how "The code does send Encoding.UTF8.GetByte() byte properly but not the image." is related to the post.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov alright ill try that, ill go ahead and suspend the question for now and thanks.

Comment: That's how TCP works, you only get the data that happens to be available.  64KB is probably the "window size" that was negotiated for the connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TCP is not a "byte[] in same byte[] out" system. You could have a Write split in to multiple reads or even have multiple writes combined in to a single read.

What you need to do is implement [Message Framing](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/04/message-framing.html) in your code. That means you need to send extra data that your receiving side understands to know how much data was sent in a single "message".

Here is a very simple example where the length is sent before the picture then the other side reads the length then reads that number of bytes.

Client code

```
using(TcpClient client = new TcpClient())
{
    client.Connect(IPAddress.Parse("123.456.789.123"), 12345);
    using (var clientStream = client.GetStream()) 
    {
        int imageLength = reader.ReadInt32();
        byte[] imagebyte = new byte[imageLength);
        int readBytes = 0;
        while (readBytes < imageLength)
        {
             int nextReadSize = Math.Min(client.Available, imageLength - readBytes);
             readBytes += await clientStream.ReadAsync(imagebyte, readBytes, nextReadSize);
        }
        File.WriteAllBytes("Screenshot.png",imageByte);
    }
}
```

Server code

```
TcpListener server = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any,12345);
using(TcpClient client = await server.AcceptTcpClientAsync()) 
{
    byte[] imagebyte = File.ReadAllBytes("ImageCaptured.temp");
    using(BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(client.GetStream()))
    {
        writer.Write(imagebyte.Length)
        writer.Write(imagebyte, 0, imagebyte.Length);
    }
    File.Delete("ImageCaptured.temp");
}
```

Note for the client, if you where not planning on closing the TcpClient and sending more data you would need to replace the `using(BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(client.GetStream()))` with `using(BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(client.GetStream(), Encoding.UTF8, true))`

Comment: Alright thanks for the help, ill go ahead and modify the code to something similar of what you already provided and let you know the result.

Comment: Hey for your code, I just reviewed it now, there are some errors which includes that client is sending the image to the server and the server receives it and this code `int imageLength = reader.ReadInt32();` was invalid due to missing object `reader`.

Comment: This code actually worked and help me a bit after did some fixes and modification, thank you.